# Problem when using spy and positioning library

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem using spy and positioning tikzlibraries at the same time. The outlined positions of spypoint and the magnifyglass are wrong when positioning is enabled. In the example the red circles are manually drawn at the correct positions and the black ones are automaticaly drawn by the spy function.
The problem disappers when the positioning part `\node[`**`below right=1cm and 1cm of nodeA.north east`**`...` is turned off.
Any ideas, how to fix that?
Thanks in Advance.
Cheers,
Hagen.
[image: Beispiel]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (nodeA) {};
\node[below right=1cm and 1cm of nodeA.north east] (nodeB) {
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={circle,magnification =2}, connect spies]
\begin{axis}[domain=0:2*pi]
    
      \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
       \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:pi/2,1);
       \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:pi/2,-0.5);
      \end{axis}
      \spy[size=2cm] on (spypoint) in node at (magnifyglass);
      \draw[red] (spypoint) circle (0.5cm);
      \draw[red] (magnifyglass) circle (1cm);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You nest a tikzpicture inside a node, this could create your problems.

Comment: How will you use node `nodeA`?